# SQL - query to report MAX DATE results or NULL results

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I have an SQL database with 3 tables:

1. `Customer record` table, holding master data (each row is unique)
2. `Customer notes`, each note data/time stamped (there could be many notes per customer, or none at all)
3. `Product` table, showing which customer has bought which product

   **Table: tbl_Customer_Records**
   CustomerID----    Company Name-----Company Segment----- Promo Code

   **Table: tbl_Customer_Notes**
   CustomerID----    Note-----Created Date

   **Table: tbl_Customer_Products**
   CustomerID----    Product Category

What I want is to pull a list of customer records which includes the latest note only, so there are no duplicate lines if multiple notes exist.  But I also want my report to include customer records if **no notes** exist at all.  I've achieved the first part of this with a SELECT MAX function, and that works well, the problem is when I add the OR = NULL clause in the final line of code below.  This doesn't work, and I can't figure out a solution.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

```
SELECT        

[tbl_Customer_Records].[CustomerID], 
[tbl_Customer_Records].[Company Name], 
[tbl_Customer_Records].[Company Segment], 
[tbl_Customer_Records].[Promo Code], 
[tbl_Customer_Notes].[Note],
[tbl_Customer_Products].[Product Category]

FROM            

tbl_Customer_Records
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_Customer_Notes
ON tbl_Customer_Records.CustomerID = tbl_Customer_Notes.CustomerID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_Customer_Products
ON tbl_Customer_Records.CustomerID = tbl_Customer_Products.CustomerID

WHERE  
[Product Category] in ('Nuts','Bolts','Screws','Spanners') 

AND 

[Created Date] in (SELECT MAX ([Created Date]) FROM tbl.Customer_Notes GROUP BY [CustomerID]) 

OR tbl_Customer_Note.Note is null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're a few tricks to do this kind of query (row_number or join with grouped data), but I think most cleanest one in your case is to use outer apply:

```
select
   cr.[CustomerID], 
   cr.[Company Name], 
   cr.[Company Segment], 
   cr.[Promo Code], 
   cn.[Note],
   cp.[Product Category]
from tbl_Customer_Records as cr
    left outer join tbl_Customer_Products as cp on cp.CustomerID = cr.CustomerID
    outer apply (
        select top 1
            t.[Note]
        from tbl_Customer_Notes as t
        where t.[CustomerID] = cr.[CustomerID]
        order by t.[Created_Date] desc
    ) as cn
where
    cp.[Product Category] in ('Nuts','Bolts','Screws','Spanners')
```

Changed all clumsy `table name.column name` to `alias.column name`, I think it's much more readable this way.

Or:

```
select
    cr.[CustomerID], 
    cr.[Company Name], 
    cr.[Company Segment], 
    cr.[Promo Code], 
    cn.[Note],
    cp.[Product Category]
from tbl_Customer_Records as cr
    left outer join tbl_Customer_Products as cp on cp.CustomerID = cr.CustomerID
    left outer join tbl_Customer_Notes as cn on
        cn.CustomerID = cr.CustomerID and
        cn.[Created_Date] = (select max(t.[Created_Date]) from tbl_Customer_Notes as t where t.CustomerID = cr.CustomerID)
where
    cp.[Product Category] in ('Nuts','Bolts','Screws','Spanners')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Point taken about the clumsy column names, I'll bear that in mind in the future.  Interestingly, your first solution returns 4,315 results and the second 4,393 results - same as Deepshikha's solution.  Thanks for both the suggestions, I'm keeping a note of the syntax for future use.  Many thanks for taking the time to help! Daniel

Comment: First one returns arbitrary record if there's more than one record with max(Created_Date)

Comment: Ah, yes I understand. I do actually have multiple notes with the same CreatedDate so your first solution works better in this situation.  Thanks again. (Changed the accepted answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can add your filter condition in `ON` predicate to preserve rows from left table and fetch only required matching rows from right table, from first LEFT OUTER JOIN operator. Following query should work:

```
SELECT        
CR.[CustomerID], 
CR.[Company_Name], 
CR.[Company_Segment], 
CR.[Promo_Code], 
CN.[Note],
CP.[Product_Category]
FROM            
tbl_Customer_Records CR
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_Customer_Notes CN
ON CR.CustomerID = CN.CustomerID AND CN.[Created_Date] in (SELECT MAX ([Created_Date]) 
                                                           FROM tbl_Customer_Notes 
                                                           WHERE CR.CustomerID =  tbl_Customer_Notes.CustomerID 
                                                           GROUP BY [CustomerID]) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_Customer_Products CP
ON CR.CustomerID = CP.CustomerID
WHERE  
[Product_Category] in ('Nuts','Bolts','Screws','Spanners')
```

Comment: Thanks for the code - really is appreciated. I ran this code and it returns 4,393 results on my dataset so I'll keep this code as the accepted answer.  Thanks for taking the time to help!  Cheers, Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Should work, tried with NULL values:

```
SELECT a.[CustomerID], 
       a.[Company Name], 
       a.[Company Segment], 
       a.[Promo Code], 
       a.[Note],
       a.[Product Category]
FROM (
SELECT        
cr.[CustomerID], 
cr.[Company Name], 
cr.[Company Segment], 
cr.[Promo Code], 
cn.[Note],
cp.[Product Category],
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cr.[CustomerID] ORDER BY cn.[Created Date] DESC) as rnk
FROM tbl_Customer_Records cr
LEFT JOIN tbl_Customer_Notes cn
ON cr.CustomerID = cn.CustomerID 
LEFT JOIN tbl_Customer_Products cp
ON cr.CustomerID = cp.CustomerID
WHERE cp.[Product Category] in ('Nuts','Bolts','Screws','Spanners') )a
WHERE a.rnk = 1
```

Comment: Thanks a mill for the code, much appreciated.  Interestingly, the code returns 4049 results which is a little less than some of the other solutions suggested.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to use  `CustomerID not in (select CustomerID from tbl_Customer_Note)`